# RabbitMQ queue sharding and HA

Tags: rabbitmq

I wonder if it possible to have a cluster with HA and sharding queues on the same machine?

I'll explain by example:

```
Machine1: 
    Queues: 
        Queue_001
        Queue_002
    HA: 
        Copy of the queues of machine2 (003 and 004)
        
Machine2: 
    Queues: 
        Queue_003
        Queue_004
    HA: 
        Copy of the queues of machine1 (001 and 002)
```

As you can see, if you take one of those servers, the other server has all the needed information in order to answer requests.

Basically, the advantage of architecture like this is:

1. HA
2. Performance. Since we are using both machines to serve data. In contrast to a situation that the replica is just for backup.

This architecture is possible with RabbitMQ?

Comment: As far as I understand the discussion on the rabbitmq-sharding plugin website right, the combination of queue sharding and HA should work: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding/issues/34


Unfortunatelly I have no experience with it and no idea how this approach performs in outtage situations.